# passing properties value to view model

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm stuck here with my first app. Everything is plain and simple till now. I navigated from one view to another and passed data from one view to another. But now I want to take a property value from a view to the model data. here is the sample format.

```
struct QuestionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var questionManager : QuestionManager
    var index : Int
    @State var isMarked = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                Text("QUESTION \(questionManager.index)")
                Image(systemName: questionManager.isMarked ? "flag.fill" : "flag")
                    .onTapGesture {
                     questionManager.isMarked.toggle()
                     }
                Text(questionManager.question)
                }.environmentObject(questionManager)
                 .onAppear{questionManager.setQuestion()}
        }
    }
```

the above question view takes the index value from another View. but below is my model on which my question is based.

```
class QuestionManager : ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var questions : [Question] = []
    @Published var index = 0
    @Published private(set) var question = ""
    @Published private(set) var isMarked = false

    func load{....json loader......}
    init() {
            self.questions = load("questions.json")
           }
    func setQuestion() {
        answerSelected = false
        
        if index < questions.count {
            
            let currentQuestion = questions[index]
            question = currentQuestion.question
            
        }
    }
```

My model data loads the data from a json data. As you can see here that the index here is different than the index in `QuestionView` which is changed every time I navigate to a different question. I want to bind that index from `QuestionView` to this `QuestionManager` index value which is really important for the function `setQuestion()`. How can I bind these two variables? And how can I bind the `isMarked` properties to each questions `isMarked` property?

Comment: The code cannot compile. `questionManager.isMarked.toggle()` must throw an error because the property is `private(set)`

Comment: Why not just use `questionManager.index` instead?

Comment: thangs @vadian this is fixed now as a normal published var.

Comment: @Yrb. How do I dow that from another view. in another view I have the following code 
    ForEach(0..<40){i in
                        NavigationLink(destination: QuestionView(index:i+1)){
                            
                                Text("Question \(i+1)")
                                    .environmentObject(questionManager)
                            
                            }
Here in another view I am using ForEach loop to loop through the range and passing the i to question view as a value to the index.

Comment: Please don't post code in the comments. Edit the question. This is all code you should have had in there in the first place. This needs a [Minimal Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).